# User.Identity.Name is empty in Asp.NET Core 2.0 API Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0, bearer-token, asp.net-core-identity

I am new to ASP.NET core itself. However, I am creating WebAPIs in ASP.NET Core 2.0.  I have configured JWT Bearer Token based authentication. Below is my Controller which return token.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<UserEntity> userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<UserEntity> signInManager;

    public TokenController(UserManager<UserEntity> userManager, SignInManager<UserEntity> signInManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string username, string password, string grant_type)
    {
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var result =await signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    var claims = new[]
                    {
                        new Claim( JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username),
                        new Claim( JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                        new Claim( JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, "SomeUserID")
                    };

                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretesecretesecretesecretesecretesecrete"));
                    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken( issuer: "test",
                                                     audience: "test",
                                                     claims: claims,
                                                      expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(15),
                                                      signingCredentials: creds);

                    return Ok(new { access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token), expires_on=DateTime.Now.AddDays(15) });

                }
            }
        }

        return BadRequest("Could not create token");
    }


}
```

But when calling ValuesController API which is decorated with **[Authorize]** attributes. I am getting  **User.Identity.Name** is empty.  I am not getting any information about user.  I am not sure, My token controller is correctly written.  As long as it is protecting my ValuesController, I assume, it is correct.  However, I might be missing something.  Please help.

> Note: I am developing using Visual Studio 2017 with Mac Community
>   addition

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify the claim for the unique name which is translated into the user.identity.name:

```
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)
```

Comment: I am having another issue after this.  userManager.GetUserAsyc(User) is returning null. However User.Identity.Name is returning me right value. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try GetUserByName or Email instead

Comment: I used FindByNameAsync method in the last. Thanks,  I tried above method as User was populated with value.  But I guess, it won't work for JWT token.

Comment: I thought we wouldn't have to especially use user.UserName to reach Identity.Name. But it worked.

Comment: I tried, but its not working still getting null and User.Claims also getting empty array.

Comment: Where are you adding/doing this?

Answer (score 25):

I've also been having this problem with ASP.Net Core 2, and I'm really surprised no one's discovered the other cause of this problem.

When my webapp is deployed to IIS, "`User.Identity.Name`" always returns null.  The IIS site has anonymous access disabled, and windows authentication is enabled.

BUT.

I didn't realise that my ASP.Net Core 2 has a "`launchSettings.json`" file, quietly hidden under the `Properties` folder, and in there, there's also some iisSettings, and in here "`windowsAuthentication`" was, strangely, set as false by default.

[image]

Changing "`windowsAuthentication`" to true, and "`anonymousAuthentication`" to false solved the problem for me.

After doing this, "`User.Identity.Name`" did finally contain the correct username.

But what the heck is this setting ?  Why would *this* get priority over the actual settings we've setup in IIS Manager ?!

Comment: Why was this voted down ? This is exactly relevant to the question asked, and this answer hasn't been presented anywhere else. Isn't that the point of StackOverflow ?

Comment: Maybe it didn't solve the problem for everybody, like mine is still broken after trying your suggested fix.

Comment: Because it didn't solve the problem for everybody doesn't mean it isn't a valid cause. I don't think this deserves the downvotes. I'd disagree with Mike's argument, though—settings in `launchSettings.json`should _always_ override settings on the IIS server. How else do you get to set general conditions and allow some applications to override them? So, it's a good answer to the original question, but the last paragraph is unnecessary.

Comment: @MikeGledhill In my case as well, it worked perfectly. Stackoverflow must ask for a comment before downvotting..

Comment: That finger is disturbing somehow

Answer (score 8):

Had this problem too (Core 3.1) using the "DefaultIdentity" (Individual User Accounts).
User.Identity.Name is null, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true.
By using httpContextAccessor you can get the userId an with that id you can find the user and the UserName.
In your controller add

```
using System.Security.Claims;
...
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
public MyController(MyContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
  _context = context;
  _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

// Any method username needed
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyInfo>> GetMyInfo(int id)
{
  var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
  var user = _context.AspNetUsers.Find(userId);
  var userName = user.UserName;
  ...
}
```

In the Startup.cs add the following line:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Thanks, saved me a alot of time figuring out!

Comment: You dont need to use HttpContextAccessor in Controller. You already have HttpContext.User in controller.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure OAuth v2, use preferred_username instead of unique_name ([see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens)).

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;

serviceCollection.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";
    //options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "email"; // or if you want to use user's email for User.Identity.Name

    //below lines of code can be removed. just there if you want some code to be executed right after user is validated. 
    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
    {
        var personFirstName = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("given_name") ?? string.Empty;
        var personLastName = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("family_name") ?? string.Empty;
        var personEmail = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("email")?.ToLower();
        var personName = context.Principal.Identity.Name;
    };
});
```

Then in your controllers, you will get username from User.Identity.Name