# Asp .Net Core 5 Identity - How to fetch a user?

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0, reactjs.net

In the new SPA (react and angular) web templates for .Net core 5. I'd like to fetch the current logged in User. However, when I try to get a user in the controller the User doesn't have anything populated.

Does anyone know how to achieve this with the new Identity Classes?

I've made a [repo](https://github.com/nicholasbergesen/timstemplate) of the vanilla reactJS template, the only thing I changed is the line highlighted in my screenshot below to show there's no user set.

I've done a bit of googling and these pages are all I could find on the topic, unfortunately, they don't give enough detail for me to be able to implement anything practical.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0

[image]

Comment: This may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820767/user-identity-name-is-empty-in-asp-net-core-2-0-api-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820767/user-identity-name-is-empty-in-asp-net-core-2-0-api-controller).

Comment: Hi @OfirD I don't have any JWT bearer confiruation. I'm hoping to be able to use the identity code "out the box". Unfortunately the post your liked doesn't give any details on their configuration in the startup class to use the Token service they created so I'm unable to use that in my case.

Answer (score 0):

#### Backend:

```
ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
var currentUserName = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(currentUserName);
```

###### On the frontend *if you need yo access it*

```
 //with UserManager
 UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
   @{
      var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
     }

 // with SignInManager
 SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
   @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
```

Comment: There is no front end because its hidden inside the AddDefaultIdentity service.
User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value; does successfully return the user Id.

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question.

In order to populate the User detail in the HttpContext you have 1 of 2 routes. Either change

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>();
```

to

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
```

or you can continue to use the Core Identity

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>();
```

but then you also need to implement your own Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator and add it as transient `services.AddTransient<ISecurityStampValidator, MyValidator>();`
Your MyValidator implementation will be responsible for validating the cookie. You can see the default implementation [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/SecurityStampValidator.cs) on github

Edit: Under the hood `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>();` uses `services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>();`. I feel like its importatnt to know this.