# ASP.NET Controller User property not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, .net-6.0

I am trying to do something seemingly very simple. All I want to do is get the current Identity User's email address for my Blazor view. I have a `UserEmailController` in my Server project, with a `GetCurrent()` method that returns a `Task<string>`.

```
public class UserEmailsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public UserEmailsController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/currentUser")]
        public async Task<string> GetCurrent()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            return await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
        }
    }
```

From the spelunking I've done, it seems that the `User` property on the `Controller` base class should have the information loaded into it when a user is logged in, and I should be able to do something like `await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)`. However, when I break on this line, the `Name` property of `User` is `null`, along with many of the other values. But `IsAuthenticated` is true. Huh?

So, the result of the `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` call is `null`.

I've seen a few posts about this, and there are two common themes.

#1 - people try to use the `User` property in the constructor of a controller and it doesn't work. The suggested solution is to use it in an Action instead, which is of course what I'm doing.

#2 - another common suggestion is to use `HttpContext.User`, or to inject an `IHttpContextAccessor` (added via `services.AddSingleton...` or `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`). I've tried all of these approaches and I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61185262/4064933). Specifically using `HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)` and then passing that into `_userManager.FindByIdAsync(nameId)`. Hell of a roundabout way of doing it, but it works.